# TypeOrm doesn't save entity with it's relation on update

Tags: postgresql, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

Given the following relation:

```
@Entity({name: 'accounts'})
export class Account {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @OneToOne(type => Address, address => address.id)
  @JoinColumn({name: 'address_id'})
  address: Address;

  @Column()
  name: string;
}
```

And the addres relation:

```
@Entity({name: 'addresses'})
export class Address {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column({length: 45})
  country: string;
}
```

When I get the `account` entity by this:

```
  /**
   * Gets account by haccount ID with ALL relations
   * @param accountId The account ID
   */
  public async getAccountByAccountIdWithRelations(accountId: string): Promise<Account> {
    return await this.findOneOrFail({id: accountId}, {relations: ['address']});
  }
```

I get the full `Account` entity with the `Address` relation in it.

And then when I do the following:

```
account.address.country = 'newcountry';
```

and do `this.save(account)` in `accountRepository` the address won't update at all!

*When I do console log before the save, I see the `account` entity with the updated address, so this is something really strange!*

Why is it happening?

**Note: All queries are done in a transaction; I dont know if it matters**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cascade should be set. Here is an example of mine entities:

```
@Entity()
@Index([ 'studyId', 'teamId', 'enterdate' ])
export class DataMessage extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment') id: number;

    @CreateDateColumn() enterdate: Date;
    @UpdateDateColumn({ select: false })
    updatedAt?: Date;
    @Column() owner: string;
    @Column() studyId: number;
    @Column() teamId: number;
    @Column() patient: string;
    @Column() orderId: number;
    @Column({ default: DataMessageStatus.OPEN })
    status: DataMessageStatus;

    @Column()
    @Index()
    resultId: number;

    @OneToMany(() => DataMessageContent, (c) => c.message, { cascade: true })
    contents: DataMessageContent[];
}

@Entity()
export class DataMessageContent extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment') id: number;

    @CreateDateColumn() enterdate: Date;
    @Column() owner: string;
    @Column() role: UserRole;
    @Column({ default: MessageStatus.UNREAD })
    status: MessageStatus;

    @Column() txt: string;

    @ManyToOne(() => DataMessage, (m) => m.contents)
    message: DataMessage;
}
```

This should also work for onetoone relation as well.

Comment: Can you add some more context around your answer?

Comment: I've added a complete example

Comment: That's right, cascade makes it delete and save recursive, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Doing that kind of update on sql is quite complicated and even with queryBuilder TypeORM doesn't support join updates (you can see it [here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/564)). The relation selector is quite helpfull but I would advise you to use it when its really necesary and add a nullable field to get the Ids of the address and obtain the address on separate it makes the things a lot easier in cases you need to change that relation lets say when you want to change the whole address object. this would be the result in the relations:

```
@Entity({name: 'accounts'})
export class Account {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  address_id: string;

  @OneToOne(type => Address, address => address.id)
  @JoinColumn({name: 'address_id'})
  address: Address;

  @Column()
  name: string;
}
```

And you can keep calling the relation as you did before with:

```
public async getAccountByAccountIdWithRelations(accountId: string): Promise<Account> {
    return await this.findOneOrFail({id: accountId}, {relations: ['address']});
  }
```

Using this aproach would keep inserting and updating easy and it works also in the oneToMany => manyToOne Relations too